# sorting table progress in angular

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-orderby

my problem is sorting a table in angular, where I have a column that is displaying progress in x/x, e.g. 3/10

I have a header that changes the sorting column to that column when clicked, but when I click it it does not reverse the sorting as it should.

table:

```
<table ng-controller="tabledata">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="sortcol='name'">Name
                 <span ng-if="reverse && sortcol=='name'" ng-click="reverse=!reverse">▲</span>
                 <span ng-if="!reverse && sortcol=='name'" ng-click="reverse=!reverse">▼</span>
           </th>
           <th ng-click="sortcol='progress'">Progress
                 <span ng-if="reverse && sortcol=='progress'" ng-click="reverse=!reverse">▲</span>
                 <span ng-if="!reverse && sortcol=='progress'" ng-click="reverse=!reverse">▼</span>
           </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:sortcol:reverse">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.progress}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

controller:

```
module.controller('tabledata',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.sortcol = 'name';
    $scope.items = [{"name":"item1","progress":"1/20"},{"name":"item2","progress":"5/10"},{"name":"item3","progress":"2/10"}];
}]);
```

so when it not reversed it should sort:

item1 1/20
item3 2/10
item2 5/10

and when reversed:

item2 5/10
item3 2/10
item1 1/20

or the other way around, i really don't care

but nothing is changed, and the sort stay the same, reversed or not reversed! (I can get it to sort by name, no problem there)

I have tried to make a function and set ng-click="sortcol='sortPercent'" on the table header, and adding following function to the controller, but the function is never called on click. (I tried adding a console.log in the function and it never displayed).

```
$scope.sortPercent = function(data){
    var pdata = data.progress.split("/");
    return (pdata[0]-pdata[1]);
 }
```

any help would be appreciated :-)

cheers
c_bb

Comment: start by using valid html

Comment: not me that needs to be happy, but when you post invalid code that is one of the first things that gets noticed. How do we know if that isn't part of a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `ng-if` used instead of `ng-show`. `ng-if` doesn't work in combination with `ng-click` because `ng-if` actually defines it's own `$scope`

```
 <span ng-show="reverse && sortcol=='name'" ng-click="reverse=!reverse">▲</span>
 <span ng-show="!reverse && sortcol=='name'" ng-click="reverse=!reverse">▼</span>
```

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YDPqBF41kJEUFitcWucz?p=preview)